# Invocar método da classe filha em C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Tenho uma classe/estrutura pai e uma classe/estrutura filha em C++. A classe pai define um método, e a classe filha sobrecarrega esse método.

Exemplo trivial:

```
struct Pai {
    
    void imprimir() {
        std::cout << "Classe pai" << "\n";
    }
    
};

struct Filha : Pai {

    void imprimir() {
        std::cout << "Classe filha" << "\n";
    }

};
```

Quero declarar uma variável do tipo `Pai`, essa variável pode ser inicializada com uma instãncia de `Pai`, ou de qualquer outra classe que herda a mesma:

```
Pai obj = Filha{};
```

Meu problema ocorre ao invocar o método dessa instancia. Em linguagens como Java ou C#, é de se esperar que o método invocado seja o pertencente a instancia da classe armazenada na variável "obj", ou seja, deveria imprimir "Classe filha".

Mas em C++ o que ocorre é que o programa invoca o método da mesma classe que a variável é declarada, invoca o método da classe `Pai`, imprimindo "Classe pai".

Há algo que eu possa fazer para que ao invocar o método "imprimir", seja invocado o método declarado na classe filha?

[Aqui](https://ideone.com/Dibt0d) tem o código rodando para melhor visualização.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer herança em um tipo por valor, isso não acontece como espera. Para fazer polimorfismo em tipo por valor precisa usar um mecanismo de *template* ou algo mais complexo, mas nem tente sem dominar muito todos aspectos da programação em C++, como a memória se comporta nessas situações. Quase sempre esse tipo de polimorfismo é um erro, e só parece ser certo em um exemplo tão artificial onde os nomes dos tipos nem possuem significado.

Programar orientado a objeto é dar significado para as coisas, quando não se dá nomes, não tem significado e não se usa OOP do jeito certo, nunca.

Então para fazer igual Java ou C# precisa fazer isso com um objeto por referência, porque é assim que essas linguagens fazem.

E precisa dizer que o método é virtual porque sem isso ele o polimorfismo não é ativado, igual ao C# (não é igual ao Java porque ele é ativado sempre, o que é um erro da linguagem).

Então teria que fazer algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Pai {
    virtual void imprimir() {
        cout << "Classe pai\n";
    }
};

struct Filha : Pai {
    void imprimir() override {
        cout << "Classe filha\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Pai *obj = new Filha{};
    obj->imprimir();
    delete obj;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/O5eSdQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rqzlnfdq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/PolymorphismStruct.cpp).

Mas não estou recomendando criar algo real dessa forma, estou apenas demonstrando como o mecanismo funcionaria se ele fosse o adequado. Nem é a melhor forma de escrever esse código.

Comment: Eu estou particularmente preocupado com o método destrutor, é possível declarar esse "override" no destrutor da classe Filha também?

Comment: Isso é outra questão, mas pode sim, e em muitos casos deve se ele é necessário. Só tenho medo de um destrutor em um tipo por valor.

Comment: Bom, "smart pointers" implementam destrutores apesar de serem um tipo por valor, não? O exemplo que eu dei foi utilizado apenas para não poluir a pergunta.

Comment: Por isso que eu tenho medo e não que seja proibido. É muito raro ser útil, quase sempre será uma invenção sem a pessoa entender porque está fazendo aquilo. Os *smart pointer*, não devem ser herdados. O problema da programação é que tudo pode ser composto, o que é lindo sozinho não funciona com outras coisas. Junte polimorfismo em destrutor em tipo que deveria ser por valor mas o objeto foi criado com referência para funcionar...

Answer (score 3):

> Há algo que eu possa fazer para que ao invocar o método "imprimir", seja invocado o método declarado na classe filha?
>
> `Pai obj = Filha{};`

Sim, mas é complicado.
Quando vc cria um objeto Filho e guarda ele em uma variável Pai, toda informação inerente de Filho é perdida. Às vezes, quando isso é desejável, pode-se usar classes abstratas ou funções virtuais em Pai, selecionando pontos de sobrecarga, para que então Pai seja composto por membros de Filho:

```cpp
struct Pai {
    virtual void imprimir()=0;
};

struct Filha : Pai {
    void imprimir() override {
        std::cout << "Classe filha" << "\n";
    }
};

//...

Pai* obj = new Filha{};
obj->imprimir();
```

Essa técnica é conhecida como type erasure e é parte fundamental de alguns componentes da STL, como std::function. Funções virtuais vem com uma penalidade de performance considerável e não são sempre a melhor solução para toda situação, por isso que essa funcionalidade não ocorre automaticamente como em línguas puramente orientadas a objetos (Java, C#, etc).

Através de templates é possível que Pai tenha informações sobre Filho sem recorrer a funções virtuais com uma técnica chamada CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern).

```cpp
template <typename TipoFilho>
struct PaiCRTP {
    void imprimir() {
        auto filho = static_cast<TipoFilho*>(this);
        filho->imp();
    }
};
struct FilhaCRTP : PaiCRTP<FilhaCRTP> {
    void imp() {
        std::cout << "Classe filha" << "\n";
    }
};
template <typename TipoFilho>
void imprime(PaiCRTP<TipoFilho>& pai) {
    pai.imprimir();
}

int main()
{
    FilhaCRTP filha;
    imprime(filha);
}
```

Nessa implementação, Pai tem a informação sobre Filho e pode invocar métodos de Filho. Filho herda Pai usando Filho como template. A função imprime é necessária para que exista um template genérico para todas combinações de Pai e Filho.